Understanding FetchAPI in vue + TS
I am developing a simple notes app. I need to fetch data from the server and then render it. I have a bunch of ready components and working backend, but kinda struggle with fetching data. When I', trying to build it gives me errors. Also would like to ask if ts would type cast the response correctly as there are some extra fields.
App.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
import Form from "./components/Form.vue";
import NoteItem from "./components/NoteItem.vue";

type Note = {
    title: string;
    content: string;
}

let loaded = false;
let noNotes = false;
const telegramId = "test"
const notes: Promise<Note[]> = fetch(`http://localhost:3000/notes/${telegramId}`)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status === 404) {
        noNotes = true;
      }

      return res.json() as Note[];
    })
    .then(() => loaded = true)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center justify-items-center h-screen space-x-4 gap-0">
    <h1 class="font-bold h-max text-6xl font-serif underline decoration-sky-500">Notes</h1>
    <Form/>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 w-1/3 mt-8 gap-4">
      <div v-if="loaded">
        <div v-for="note in notes">
          <NoteItem :title="note.title" :content="note.content"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <h2 v-if="noNotes"></h2>
        <h2 v-else>Fetching...</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>

Response example:
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2024-10-16T18:17:25.141109Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2024-10-16T18:17:25.141109Z",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "TelegramId": "test",
        "Title": "Test3",
        "Content": "Test3"
    }
]

Errors:
src/App.vue:13:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Promise<boolean | void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Note[]>'.
  Type 'boolean | void' is not assignable to type 'Note[]'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Note[]'.

13 const notes: Promise<Note[]> = fetch(`http://localhost:3000/notes/${telegramId}`)
         ~~~~~

src/App.vue:19:14 - error TS2352: Conversion of type 'Promise<any>' to type 'Note[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Note[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.

19       return res.json() as Note[];
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/App.vue:32:34 - error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string | (<TResult1 = Note[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Note[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<...>) | .....'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.

32           <NoteItem :title="note.title" :content="note.content"/>
                                    ~~~~~

src/App.vue:32:56 - error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'string | (<TResult1 = Note[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Note[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<...>) | .....'.
  Property 'content' does not exist on type 'string'.

32           <NoteItem :title="note.title" :content="note.content"/>


res.json() returns a promise of Note[], not Note[]

@EstusFlask Okay, minus one error, but the second one still kinda confuses me

so i added const notes: Promise<Note[]> | any to bypass errors but now my page is blank and nothing renders (with no errors in console btw)

The whole thing isn't workable. notes can't be used in a view because it's a promise of data, not data. You need to either make the component async with const notes = await fetch... and use  in parent component. Or use reactivity correctly like const notes = ref() and move fetch() to onMounted() and do .then(result => { notes.value = result }), because "loaded` doesn't serve a good purpose without data to show, and it's not reactive any way

@EstusFlask yeah, forgot to mention that I've already added await fetch.... How should  thing look like?

Btw in a chain, .then(() => loaded = true) means your Promise resolves to a boolean, not what the previous then returnend (i.e. not Notes[]). Compare to .then(v => (loaded = true, v)), which propagates the input value.

@Sanyokk There should be a component that is a parent to the one where you're doing this, i.e. extract the whole thing to something like Notes and do <Suspense><Notes/><template #fallback>Fetching</template></Suspense> in App, it's intended for what you're trying to do with loading status

Answers are scattered in the comments, let me summarize them.
In your code, notes is Promise<Note[]>, which is not iterable. fetch is asynchronous. When the component is rendered, fetch may not have even started yet.
You can add a loading placeholder like this:
<script lang="ts" setup>
const notes = ref<Note[] | undefined>(); // Use `ref` to ensure reactivity
fetch(...).then(...)
</script>

<template>
  <p v-if="typeof notes === 'undefined'">loading...</p>
  <div> <!-- `notes` is narrowed to `Note[]` here --> </div>
</template>

And you can use await to make it tidier, but the component will become asynchronous. Then the component itself don't need to manage the loading placeholder, but the parent component do by <Suspense>. Like:
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <NotesArea>
    <template #fallback>
      Loading...
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>

When using await, remember that App.vue can't be asynchronous. You can extract this into another SFC.
Performance note: if the number of elements of notes is large, shallowRef will have a better performance.

const fetchNotes = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/notes/${telegramId}`);
    if (response.status === 404) {
      noNotes.value = true;
      loaded.value = true;
      return;
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const notes: Note[] = data.map((item: any) => ({
      title: item.Title,
      content: item.Content
    }));
    notes.value = notes;
    loaded.value = true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
